# переписать условие из bash в awk

Tags: bash, awk

Сейчас сделано так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
IFS=$'\n'
arr=($(awk '/123/ {print $0}' test.txt)) #Если в строке встречается 123 печатать строку и записывать в массив

if [ ${#arr[@]} -eq 0 ]; #если массив пустой то выводим Nothing если что-то есть - печатаем
then
    echo "Nothing"
else
    printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
fi
```

Как переписать условие с bash на awk?

мысль такая, что надо использовать BEGIN/END:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
IFS=$'\n'
awk 'BEGIN {flag = 0}
/123/ {flag=1}
END {
if (flag=0) {print "Nothing"} else {print $0}
}' test.txt #print $0 очевидно выводит только последнюю строку, а нужно вывести все которые найдены. как это организовать?
```

файл test.txt

```
String with 123
String without numbers 1
String without numbers 2
String without numbers 123
String without numbers 3
String 123 with numbers
```

Comment: не совсем понимаю, что смущает в варианте из вопроса... разве только то что синтаксические и логические ошибки надо подправить, но идея вполне рабочая...

Comment: Да рабочая и работает, просто хочу переписать на awk. Хочу, научиться-разобраться.

Comment: я про уже переписанный вариант...

Comment: Поправил свою "мысль", но возникает очевидная проблема описанная в комментарии в коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предыдущий вариант в вопросе был почти рабочим.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk 

BEGIN {flag = 0}
/123/{print $0; flag=1}
END {if (!flag) {print 'Nothing'}}
```

Да, от `BEGIN` можно отказаться — не инициализированные переменные также ложны.